# Infinite Scrollable Div with Ajax loaded Content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, gwt

I want to implement a technique called scrollable div in [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/). What I am trying to do is the following. 
If a user is on my page he can only see the viewport (green box in the image). All DOM elements that are in this viewport are visible to the user on page load. Alle DOM elements that are not on the viewport have not been loaded after a page has been loaded on page load (blue boxes in the image).

If the user drag and move the viewport, all dom elements become visible which come onto the viewport. If they are on the viewport they will be loaded via ajax.

The user can zoom in and out the viewport to make it bigger and smaller. Also, if elements that are invisible to the user and thus not loaded yet become visible, than they have to be loaded via ajax and displayed on the viewport.

How do I have to implement this with GWT?

If the user loads the page it looks like the following image:

[image]

The user can drag and move the viewport to 8 directions. These are top, top right, right, right bottom, bottom, bottom left, left and top left. The following image shows a movement to the left.
When the viewport moves new content should be loaded with ajax.

[image]

The viewport can also be zoomed in. In this case also new content should be loaded.

[image]

The viewport can also be zoomed out. Note that the viewport must be of fixed dimensions. Only the content should be zoomable.

[image]

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: @dr.dimitru not It misses a lot.

Comment: anyways after you done - please, left a link here, we would like to see the result

Comment: @dr.dimitru I do not have any result. Can you create a js fiddle? I have problems with moving the viewport.

Comment: does the full page have a fixed size (I know the view port does not)? or it changes when you get closed to the boundaries?

Comment: @Manolo Think of an iFrame embedded with fixed size in another page. This is also the fixed size of the viewport. When zoom takes place it zoomes the content in the viewport, the viewport dimensions remain unchanged. The full page size depends on the content.

Comment: http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/#/big is good one can help you a lot

Comment: @stephan1001, Does this [widget](http://mobilegwt.appspot.com/showcase/#ScrollWidgetPlace:) behave as you want? if so I'll post a solution based on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPD**:
jsfiddle EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/hv57s/9/

**UPD**:
jsfiddle with zoom in/out buttons an functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/hv57s/11/

Answer based on this example: [Indira.js Inifinite Scroll](http://indirajs.indira-cms.com/#exampleInfiniteScroll)

```
<div id="scrollableDiv" data-scroll-callback="$('#load_button').trigger('click')">
 <table>
  ...
  <tbody id="scrollable_tbody">
    <tr>
     ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <button id="load_button" onclick="load_more(page_number)">Show more</button>
</div>
<script>
var scroll_el_id = 'scrollableDiv';
var element = $('#scrollableDiv');

$(window).unbind('scroll.' + scroll_el_id).bind('scroll.' + scroll_el_id, function(event){

  var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
  var elementBottom = element[0].scrollHeight + element.offset().top;

  if(scrollBottom >= elementBottom){
    eval($(element).attr('data-scroll-callback'));
    $(window).unbind('scroll.' + scroll_el_id);
  }
});
</script>
```

Next you just append to `#scrollable_tbody` AJAX-response, like:

```
function load_more(page){

    $.ajax({type: "GET", url: 'some/url/load_more.php?page='+page,})
        .done(function( html ) { 

           $('#scrollable_tbody').append(html); 
       });
}
```

---

**UPD:**
I think you should set big size for `html,body` like:

```
html, body{ 
    min-width: 8192px; 
    width: 8192px; 
    min-height: 8192px; 
    height: 8192px;
}
```

And set viewport in size you want.

---

**But maybe it will more easier if you will set some wrap `div` right after `body` tag with**

```
div.wrap{
  overflow: scroll; 
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
/*Do not forget to change your_viewport_* to actual size, also you can do this via jQuery on the fly*/
  max-height: your_viewport_height; 
  min-height:your_viewport_height; 
  height:your_viewport_height; 
  max-width: your_viewport_width; 
  min-height:your_viewport_width; 
  height:your_viewport_width;
}
```

and inside of this element Bigger `div` which will be scrollable.

```
div.huge{ 
    min-width: 8192px; 
    width: 8192px; 
    min-height: 8192px; 
    height: 8192px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="huge">
        ...
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also do not forget to set scrolling control for all sides of elements, in example I have only Bottom line control, something like:

```
  var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
  var elementBottom = element[0].scrollHeight + element.offset().top;

  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var elementTop = element.offset().top;

  var scrollRight = $(window).scrollLeft() + $(window).width();
  var elementRight = element[0].scrollWidth - element.offset().left;

  var scrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
  var elementLeft = element.offset().left;

  if(scrollBottom >= elementBottom && scrollTop <= elementTop && scrollRight >= elementRight && scrollLeft <= elementLeft){
    eval($(element).attr('data-scroll-callback'));
    $(window).unbind('scroll.' + scroll_el_id);
  }
```

**I didn't test this, and anyways you will have to play around with this. Hope I'm point you into right direction.**

Comment: How do I have to set the background div dimensions to make its size infinite in all directions?

Comment: I think you should set big size for html,body:

Comment: How will you handle the zoom in and out?

Comment: @stephan1001 @confile To handle zoom I think better to use buttons (like on google maps) and change `"transform" : "translate3d(0px, 0px, -36px)"` on `div.huge` element - it depends from content inside of `div.huge`

Comment: @dr.dimitru can you please create a js fiddle to demostrate your idea?

Comment: @stephan1001 I'll do jsfiddle tomorrow day. But you don't have to move the viewport - you have to work (for zoom, navigation) with div in wrap element. E.g. (acc. to my example) move the: `div.huge`

Comment: @dr.dimitru okay I will have a look at your jsfiddle

Comment: @stephan1001 added zoom in/out buttons an functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/hv57s/11/

Comment: @dr.dimitru Note that the viewport must be of fixed dimensions. Only the content should be zoomable.

Comment: @stephan1001 It is fixed

Comment: @dr.dimitru can you please draw a border around the viewport that I can see that the viewport does not change its dimensions? However I do not see the drag and move of the viewport.

Comment: @stephan1001 I've added dotted border around `.wrap` which is equal to viewport: http://jsfiddle.net/hv57s/12/

Comment: @dr.dimitru What is missing now is the drag and move on the viewport. Can you add this too?

Comment: @stephan1001 it is scrollable, but: http://jsfiddle.net/hv57s/14/
But once again - It is SCROLLABLE - it's much native as for desktops and as for Mobile devices.