# Dynamic Content Loading (Infinite Scroll)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, web

So, I am building a website that has some photos on it (similar grid to Weheartit) and the main idea is that I will update those photos daily (I will put new photos on a daily bases). At first I wanted to make a pagination but then I realized that loading the content dynamically is a better idea. So, I wanted to load the content in a similar way like Weheartit (when user reaches the bottom of the page, new content is loaded and so on to infinity)... I am generally new to web design but I have a good knowledge of HTML and CSS and some base to mid knowledge on Javascript. So, I wondered if some of you could help me get on the right road of achieving my ideas. What do I need to learn to make this possible? Is it doable without PHP, do I need AJAX and so on... Thanks guys.

Comment: this question is too broad in its current format, as you show no attempt. Take some time to browse SO for similar questions - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infinite+scrollable+div for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370850/infinite-scrollable-div-with-ajax-loaded-content

Answer (score 1):

Based on how you stated your question, it seems a little vague and I'm not quite sure on what you are asking for, but I'll answer your question to the best of my ability.

First of all, I do not see why you want to load your content 'dynamically' with Javascript. Javascript is a client side language, when your server gets a request to load a webpage, all the HTML/CSS is sent to the client side. Your Javascript will only hide some of the HTML, but the data hidden still exists on the client side. For example, you can have something like this:

```
function loadpage(){
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display= "block";
}
```

Then add a button at the end of the page that will execute this function. But it would be much better to just have it all loaded at first.

PHP is a server side language, this code is executed on the server. When you request a page, not all the html is sent to your computer... It's when you trigger an Action on the page, where the server kicks in and most likely fetches new HTML from a database on the server.

AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript and XML) is a way of communicating with the server using Javascript, it allows webpages to render information from databases without refreshing the page.

The We Heart It site generates the data dynamically from a database. When you get to the bottom of the page, an AJAX Request fires off communicating with the server loading more pictures for you to see.

If you really want a dynamic system where pictures just keep loading, you'll need to learn [PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/)/[AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)/[mySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)(DATABASE)